# How do I go to a specific part of matlab code based on my menu choice?

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab code to run an RRR Lego robot arm with EV3 brick and a mix of NXT &EV3 motors and sensors; RRR.m
It’s further divided into the following:
RRR_connect// 
RRR_goto_start_position// 
RRR_new_pos// 
RRR_goto_new_angle// 
RRR_goto_new_coordinate// 
RRR_return_to_start// 
RRR_disconnect//

I have a GUImenu in ‘RRR_new_pos’ where the user would have 3 choices;
1.Enter joint angles
2.Enter end-effector coordinates 
3.Quit

If the user chooses option 1, they get a form where they enter the desired angles for the 3 joints. The same with coordinates for option 2. 
Now my question is, how do I go straight to ‘RRR_goto_new_angle’ If user enters joint angles, or go to ‘RRR_goto_new_coordinate‘ if user enters end-effector coordinates or finally go to ‘RRR_disconnect‘ if users clicks on Quit?
I’ll upload the code if necessary. Please ask if there is a need for more clarification of the question.

Comment: Did you write functions, or is this all a single, long script? You need each section to be a function, then you can call the relevant function when you need to.

Comment: No, they are all separate *.m files within the main RRR.m file. ‘RRR_new_pos.m’,  ‘RRR_goto_new_angle.m’, ‘RRR_goto_new_coordinate.m’, and ‘RRR_return_to_start.m’ are in a while loop.

Comment: You cannot have files within files. Please explain the structure of your code, I’m unclear about what you have done so far. An M-file can be a script or a function. If it starts with a `function` statement it is a function M-file. You should write all of your code as function M-files.

Comment: clear;
close all;
RRR_V2_Connect
RRR_V2_WorkSpace
RRR_V2_Start_Pos
while 1
RRR_V2_New_Pos
RRR_V2_Goto_New_Pos
RRR_V2_Return_to_Start
end

brick.disconnect;
clear all;

Comment: I couldn't edit the previous comment. But the main RRR_V2.m calls them one after the other, but I want to skip one or more of them based on the user choice/input.